# The most efficient way o 3 Strings concatenation in java 8

Tags: java, string, performance, string-concatenation

I have a multithreaded Http server in Java 8
which gets thousands of requests per second and has to create responses which require *String concatenation*. What is the best (fastest) solution to this problem?

I know that in general `StringBuilder` has much better performance than `+` operator and I thought StringBuilder will be the best solution but in this case I would have to initialize new StringBuilder for each request.

Moreover, in my problem concatenation always require 3 strings - two of them are final and the middle one is a variable. The variable can take values from the set of *~20* different elements. So the number of possible concatenated strings equals *20 x number_of_different_strings* which is about *2000*.

Is it better to use StringBuilder or just concatenate Strings (the number will not exceed 2k different strings) or maybe its better to store all created Strings (about 2k) in map and ask for specific one each time?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is not always faster than `+`, you misheard or misunderstood the suggestion. The issue is that if you use `+`  inside of a loop to concatenate over and over again then it can be way more inefficient using a `StringBuilder` correctly. But if all you do is concatenate 3 values without any looping around it, then `"foo" + x + "bar"` is just fine. Have you profiled your code to verify if the string concatenation is actually the problem here?

Comment: You will probably have more overhead from `StringBuilder` than normal concatenation unless you are doing this concatenation *multiple* times for 1 *request*.

Comment: 1000 requests per second doesn't sound like a ridiculously large amount, actually. Benchmark first.

Comment: I'll be honest with you: a lot of your arguments are wrong/misleading and sound exactly like they often sound when made by people who don't really understand performance of Java programs and what does or does not affect them. You really, really should actually **profile** your code in realistic load scenarios to verify what costs the most time in your code. My gut feeling tells me it's not the string concatenation, but gut feelings are very dangerous things in these areas, so don't trust them (not mine and not yours).

Comment: Are there any known limiting factors regarding the strings? Max size, always the same size, only ASCII?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that in general `StringBuilder` has much better performance than `+` operator

That is not exactly true. In fact, when you use the `+` operator, the Java compiler will convert that into using `StringBuilder` in the compiled code.

The issue is the following. Look at the following code:

```
String[] names = {"Joe", "Susan", "Fred", "Mary"};

String result = "";
for (String name : names) {
    result = result + name;
}
```

Every time you use the `+` operator, the Java compiler will create a `StringBuilder` to perform that operation. The compiler converts the above into something like this:

```
for (String name : names) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(result);
    sb.append(name);
    result = sb.toString();
}
```

Note that this is very inefficient code. In each iteration of the loop, a new `StringBuilder` object is created. The data contained in the string `result` is copied into that `StringBuilder`. Then the next name is appended to it, and then the data in the `StringBuilder` is copied into a new `String` which is assigned to `result`. There is a lot of unnecessary copying going on.

You can write much more efficient code by using `StringBuilder` directly:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String name : names) {
    sb.append(name);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

This way, only one `StringBuilder` object is created and data is not being copied into it and into a `String` in each iteration in the loop.

If your code does not involve appending many strings in a loop, and you just have to concatenate three strings, then it does not matter if you use `+` or a `StringBuilder` explicitly. In fact, the code written with `+` would be compiled into exactly the same as what you would write when you would use `StringBuilder` manually.

Comment: Since Java 9 versions the compiler doesn't exactly convert the structure to a `StringBuilder` chaing, but [uses invokedynamic to invoke "deep Java magic"](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-concatenation-invoke-dynamic) ;-) The overall message of your answer still very much applies though.

Comment: Yes, my answer might not be *exactly* what the Java compiler is doing; it's to illustrate the idea of why using string concatenation with `+` **in a loop** is less efficient.